# Why javascript code isn't executed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test XSS vulnerabilities on some sites for a security class and I can't be able to figure out why the script injected in the following page doesn't get executed. Basically, I insert some values in an input form and the server replies with this response

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" conent="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>NECSTFeedback</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/static/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header clearfix">
        <h3 class="text-muted">The NECSTFeedback</h3>
    </div>

<h1>Report</h1>
<p><b>Subject: </b>sk</p>
<p><b>Sender: </b>as</p>
<div class="rpt-content">
    <p><b>Message: </b></p>
               <!-- This is my script -->
               <script> alert('Hi')</script>
</div>

<p><b>Attachment: </b><a href="/attachment/58224c5bd967459c925a88eb21799384"></a></p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the suspicion that it's because of the CSP header, but I'm not too sure. Btw, here is a list of the headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 19:18:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
```

Comment: Well, yes, have you looked up how CSP works? You should be able to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the suspicion that it's because of the CSP header, but I'm not too sure.
>
> ```
> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
> ```

Yes indeed.

The content security policy spec [says here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#directive-script-src):

*If 'unsafe-inline' is not in the list of [allowed script sources](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#allowed-script-sources) […]:
Whenever the user agent would execute an inline script from a [`<script>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) […], instead the user agent MUST NOT execute script […].*

That `self` in the header does definitely disallow inline scripts.

Comment: I see now, I think I skipped the 'unsafe-inline' directive at all. So, because the `default-src 'self'`, basically the only way to have a `javascript` code executed in this page is from a source file coming from the same domain as the server itself, am I right?

Comment: @tigerjack89 Yes, exactly.